# How to create a loop though folders to write rasters in corresponding folder in R?

Tags: r, loops, directory, raster

I am trying to repeat the same operations to different folders. I am stacking and multiplying several rasters 10 times (corresponding to my 10 folders).  I would like to make an operation in **dir a** and write the new rasters in **dir a**, make the operation in **dir b** and write the new rasters in **dir b**, etc.

```
setwd("path/")
dir <- list.dirs(recursive=FALSE)

for(j in 1:length(dir)){

writeRaster(stack( list.files(path=dir[j], recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE,  pattern='rain'))*2, 
          path=dir[j]),filename=paste(dir[j], "new.tif"), overwrite=TRUE,  bylayer=TRUE )
}
```

However, with the code above, the files are not written in the corresponding folders. They are all written in the path defined by **setwd**.

I am new in R and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slight modification to your code and it works. The problem was with the way you specified the name and path for writing the new raster.

```
dir <- list.dirs(recursive=FALSE)

for(j in 1:length(dir)){
writeRaster(stack( list.files(path=dir[j], recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE, pattern='rain'))*2,
paste0(dir[j],"/",strsplit(dir[j],"/")[[1]][2], "_new.tif"), overwrite=TRUE,  bylayer=TRUE )
    }
```